# Toggle wireless network settings with a little script

Tags: network-manager

I want the ability to toggle between two wireless states:

1. Only connect to Access Point A, disconnect from anything else right now, try to connect to AP-A.
2. Only connect to AP-B or AP-C, disconnect from AP-A, try to connect to anything allowed.

The second halves of each could easily be the same code (disconnect from everything, connect to anything allowed) but how do I script the first bit?

This can be achieved manually by opening the connections settings screen, editing a connection, and toggling the "Connect Automatically" checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running **nmcli** for configuring NM?

I've just played a bit with `nmcli con up id <AP essid>` and it seems that with some scripting it could probably work...